# coldfusion cfinsert fails, how to submit a query with optional fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I have this insert tag:

```
<cfquery name="aoi_results" datasource="buyerhero"  >
    INSERT INTO polygons(tract, user, name, type, center, radius, north, south, east, west, verticies)
    VALUES('#url.tract#', '#url.user#', '#url.name#', '#url.type#','#url.center#', '#url.radius#', '#url.north#', '#url.south#', '#url.east#', '#url.west#', '#url.verticies#');
</cfquery>
```

for this query, not all fields are used.  some records have `center and radius`, others have `north, south, east, and west`, and others have `verticies`.  any field not used is null.

How do I write the statement so each field after type is optional?

Thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server 2016.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cfparam` to default your url params to blank if they're not passed in. Then, in your query you can use the `null` attribute of [`cfqueryparam`](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam). The `null` attribute is a boolean, if true, it will pass in `null`.

```
<cfparam name="URL.tract" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.user" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.name" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.type" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.center" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.radius" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.north" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.south" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.east" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.west" default="" />
<cfparam name="URL.verticies" default="" />

<cfquery name="aoi_results" datasource="buyerhero"  >
    INSERT INTO polygons(tract, user, name, type, center, radius, north, south, east, west, verticies)
    VALUES(
        <cfqueryparam value="#URL.tract#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.user#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.name#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.type#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.center#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_float" null="#len(URL.center) EQ 0#" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.radius#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_float" null="#len(URL.radius) EQ 0#" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.north#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_float" null="#len(URL.north) EQ 0#" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.south#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_float" null="#len(URL.south) EQ 0#" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.east#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_float" null="#len(URL.east) EQ 0#" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.west#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_float" null="#len(URL.west) EQ 0#" />
        ,<cfqueryparam value="#URL.verticies#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_float" null="#len(URL.verticies) EQ 0#" />
    );
</cfquery>
```

I guessed on the `cfsqltype`, you'll have to verify those yourself. The `null` attribute will set the column to null if the len() is 0, and all URL parameters are defaulted to blank using `cfparam`

Most importantly, you should always use `cfqueryparam`. Passing URL variables into a query is just asking to be hacked with a SQL injection attack. [Read the query param section on learncfinaweek](http://learncfinaweek.com/week1/Databases/) for some more information on this.

Comment: that was a biblical-level answer.  Thank you SO much.  I'm going to use this from now on.  Thanks again.